# Python and Node.js

Tags: django, node.js, asynchronous, socket.io, real-time

J want to do an app in python with django but it will be real time , and I would like to use Node.js for that. I've been looking for and I discovered that I can use Socket.io and "Include" it on the template and then socket.io will execute node.js

Do you have any tutorial or idea of this ?

Comment: if all you're looking to do is use web sockets or SSE, you can do that with any language of choice (Python included).  If you're looking for an event loop in python, you can always use twisted or look at tornado.

Comment: why not give sockJs a go ? it has a python backend too.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at [this](http://www.machinalis.com/blog/rt-django-notifications/) article.

It deals with push notifications from the server to the client with Django and node.js on the server side. And socket.io to interface with the browser.